# He remembered to post a present to his mother for her sixtieth birthday. Why not use ‘posting’ instead of ‘to post’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

He remembered to post a present to his mother for her sixtieth birthday. Why not use ‘posting’ instead of ‘to post’?

I think posting is better. But the book use ‘to post’, I feel it weird.

Answer (score 1):

"Remembered to post" and "remembered posting" have different meanings. To **remember to do** something means to *not forget to do* something important or necessary, for example posting a present to one's mother in good time for her birthday. To remember doing something simply means to recall doing something.

[Remember](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remember)